# How to get substring for filter and group by clause in AWS Redshift database

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift

How to get substring from column which contains records for filter and group by clause in AWS Redshift database.

I have table with records like:

```
Table_Id | Categories         | Value
<ID>     | ABC1; ABC1-1; XYZ  | 10
<ID>     | ABC1; ABC1-2; XYZ  | 15
<ID>     | XYZ                | 5
.....
```

Now I want to filter records based on individual category like 'ABC1' or 'ABC1 and XYZ'

Expected output from query would like:

```
Table_Id | Categories         | Value
<ID>     | ABC1               | 25
<ID>     | ABC1-1             | 10
<ID>     | ABC1-2             | 15
<ID>     | XYZ                | 30
.....
```

So need to group results based on individual categories.

Comment: what is the aggregation function in the output? if it's a sum it can't be 15 for ABC1 because ABC1 is in two rows, 10+15

Comment: Yes @AlexYes, Its typo. I updated expected result.
Actually I want values for individual categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonScott, @AlexYes and other pals who struggle with similar kinda situations.

I found more better approach other than suggested by @AlexYes.

What I did, I flatter category column which result individual records.
Which I can further process.

**Query:**

```
select row_number() over(order by 1) as r1, 
        to_char(timestamptz 'epoch' + date_time * interval '1 second', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS DAY,
        split_part(categories, ';', numbers.n) as catg,
        value
    from <TABLE>
    join numbers
    on numbers.n <= regexp_count(category_string, ';') + 1 <OTHER_CONDITIONS>
```

**Explanation:**

Two functions are useful here: first, the split_part function, which takes a string, splits it on ';' delimiter, and returns the first, second, ... , nth value specified from the split string; second, regexp_count, which tells us how many times a particular pattern is found in our string.

Comment: that looks great!

Answer (score 1):

If you have at most 3 values in any "categories" cell you can unnest the cells, get the list of unique values and use that list in a join condition like this:

```
WITH
values as (
    select distinct category
    from (
            select distinct split_part(categories,';',1) as category from your_table
            union select distinct split_part(categories,';',2) from your_table
            union select distinct split_part(categories,';',3) from your_table
     )
     where nullif(category,'') is not null
)
SELECT
 t2.category
,sum(t1.value)
FROM your_table t1
JOIN values t2
ON split_part(categories,';',1)=t2.category
OR split_part(categories,';',2)=t2.category
OR split_part(categories,';',3)=t2.category
```

if you have more than 3 options just add another `split_part` level both in `WITH` part and the join condition

Comment: That's a great idea @Alexyes! I will update my answer to point to yours as the best semi-dynamic option.

Comment: Thanks @AlexYes. It seems great solution. I will update your solution to fit my requirement, as I have dynamic category string for which size is not pre-defined(category list may very in individual rows).
I will update my answer once I finalize query.

Comment: @RaviPatel you just need to know the highest possible number of options and update accordingly, I think you can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

To do this fully dynamically, you need to transpose or pivot values in "categories" column into separate rows. 
Unfortunately, a "fully dynamic" solution (without knowing the different values beforehand) is NOT possible using redshift.

Your options are as follows:

1. Use the method suggested by AlexYes in another answer. This is
   semi-dynamic and is probably your best option.
2. Outside of Redshift, run some ETL code to perform
   the column -> multiple rows ETL.
3. Create a hardcoded type solution, and perform the pivot something like this:

   select table_id,'ABC1' as category, case when concat(Categories,';') ilike '%ABC1;%' then value else 0 end as value from your_table
   union all
   select table_id,'ABC1-1' as category, case when concat(Categories,';')ilike '%ABC1-1;%' then value else 0 end as value from your_table
   union all

etc